# Canonical references for HMMs with covariates

Tags: references, hidden-markov-model

**What is/are the canonical reference(s) for HMMs with covariates?**

I'm coding some up and I'd like to follow the standard notations, if they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, GLM-type notation is used. See, e.g.,

Altman, RM (2007). Mixed Hidden Markov Models: An Extension of the Hidden Markov Model to the Longitudinal Data Setting. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 102 (477), 201-210. [[Link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27639832)]